# Moving a div element left by a few pixels

Tags: html, css, frontend

I am a newbie in front-end development, so please bear with me if the question is too basic.
What I am trying to achieve is very similar to the following problem:

How do I move the search bar on SO's website to the left without affecting the other elements? I can't use the **margin-left** property since that would move the other elements as well. Is there any way to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use margin-left negative + margin-right positive;

```
margin-left: -10px;
margin-right: 10px;
```

Comment: Or just `transform: translateX(-10px);`…

Comment: yes, there are many ways you can do it. Even position relative + left ;

Comment: That solved. Thank you all. This question got down-voted to hell.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using the `transform` property.
Use `transform: translateX(n px/vh/vw/em)`

This will not affect other elements.

There is another way to do this:

- Give the required element a position of relative
- And use `top` and `left` properties to modify the position.

**Note**: In both cases only the rendering of graphics on the screen is shifted. The element will be present in its original position.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your situation: I would say try adding “position: relative;” & “right: 10px” for  e.g.

I hope this helps!